# React: Child component not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am learning to design a bulletin board application on React that shows several "sticky notes" on a page. While the components are working correctly I believe that the "notes" on the page are rendering over each other. [Sticky Notes rendering over each other(left screen)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOlhs.png). Here is the HTML,CSS and JavaScript file of my code. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx_XCzMeXydQcm1pQ3Z6d3NOVXM

I don't think it is the problem with rendering multiple components. If I change line 86 of my render() function of Board Component in Note6.js to the following: `<h1 key={i}>{note}</h1>` and run it, it shows the output in different lines, which I hope to happen.(refer screen shot image's right window)

Please help!

Comment: You should add the code here for better results, better create fiddle so that others can modify and correct it

Answer (score 0):

Problem is probably your the position you set for the note CSS class.

```
div.note {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 2px 0;
    position: absolute; /* This line */
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

Try changing `position: absolute;` to something else, like `float: left;`